# What should be done to make TFS send e-mails for events?

Tags: tfs

Our Tfs server (Tfs2008) has smtp server installed. But we could not make Tfs send e-mails after events to the subscribers (we are using [EventSubscriptionTool](http://www.codeplex.com/tfseventsubscription)).

Our appsettings includes these lines:

```
<add key="emailNotificationFromAddress" value="tfs@mail.com" />
<add key="smtpServer" value="localhost" />
```

Is there any other tricks for this task...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sound like you have common part fixed - setting the appropriate appSettings in the web.config in %ProgramFile%\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services.

The following post from Pete Sheill might help you debug what's going wrong.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/psheill/archive/2005/11/28/497662.aspx

It was written with TFS2005 in mind, but if you replace 2005 in the paths for 2008 you'll get the gist.

Good luck,

Martin.